# PDO pagination query not executed correctly?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, pagination

I'm currently trying to make some pagination work, but without any success.

The first query I'm executing is to grab all the data needed: so first result should be on the first page, second result on the second and so on... But I'm always getting the first result. Although I copied the query into phpmyadmin to manualy set the query and there it showed me the right results.

Here's the code where everything is happening. I'm stuck why it won't work.

```
$page = isset($_GET['page']) ? $_GET['page'] : 1;
$limit = 1;
$start = 0;

$query = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `users` LIMIT $limit OFFSET $start");
$query->execute();

$result = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
$count = count($result);

$query2 = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `users`");
$query2->execute();
$result2 = $query2->fetchALL(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
$count2 = count($result2);

// Pagination

$total = ceil($count2 / $limit);

if ($page > 1) {
    $start = ($page - 1) * $limit;
}

if ($page != $total) {

    $next_page = '<li><a href="index.php?cat=users&page=' . ($page + 1) . '">&raquo;</a></li>';

} else {

    $next_page = '<li class="disabled">&raquo;</li>';

}

if ($page > 1) {

    $previous_page = '<li><a href="index.php?cat=users&page=' . ($page - 1) . '">&laquo;</a></li>';

} else {

    $previous_page = '<li class="disabled">&laquo;</li>';

}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are doing nothing with `$page`. `$start` is always 0 in the query. You're going to need to define how many records you want per page, then multiply that by $page -1, e.g. `$start = ($page - 1) * $records_per_page;`

Comment: Screw it, might as well add that as an answer...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are doing nothing with `$page`. `$start` is always 0 in the query.

You're going to need to define how many records you want per page, then multiply that by $page -1, e.g.

`$start = ($page - 1) * $records_per_page;`

Comment: Omg, now I see it... Code was actualy there, but on the wrong position. I should realy buy me a rubber duck :) Thanks tho!